# Is it possible to send a struct in a block?

Tags: ios7

I am creating a Universal Class, for **SQLite** and I am trying to send a block of `sqlite3_step`, to be processed.

In `sqlite3_step`, I am passing the struct object statement. But, it seems I need to use pointers.

How can I possibly do ir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, something like this should work:

```
typedef struct
{
    int data;
}MyStruct;

@interface Foo()

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^myBlock)(MyStruct);

@end

@implementation Foo

- (void) someMethod {
    self.myBlock = ^(MyStruct theStruct) {
        NSLog(@"Value of data in the struct %i", theStruct.data);
    };
    MyStruct theStruct;
    theStruct.data = 5;
    self.myBlock(theStruct);
}

@end
```